# Markov Chain Definition and Matrix Question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I have a question on the definition of the Markov Property and the results of multiplying an example matrix which do not agree with my expectations.

[This page](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Epollard/Courses/251.spring2013/Handouts/Chang-MarkovChains.pdf) defines the Markov Property as the following.  Does anyone how form (b) becomes (c)?  Is it due to $(X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}) \subset (X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}) \cap ... \cap (X_0 = i_0)$?  Is it due to independence of the conditional events?

a)
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_0 = i_0, X_1 = i_1, X_2 = i_2, ..., X_n = i+n)
$$
b)

$$
= \mathbb{P}(X_0 = i_0) \mathbb{P}(X_1 = i_1 | X_0 = i_0) \mathbb{P}(X_2 = i_2 | X_1 = i_1, X_0 = i_0) ... \mathbb{P}(X_n = i_n | X_{n-1} =i_{n-1} , ..., X_1 = i_1, X_0 = i_0)
$$

c)
$$
= \mathbb{P}(X_0 = i_0) \mathbb{P}(X_1 = i_1 | X_0 = i_0) \mathbb{P}(X_2 = i_2 | X_1 = i_1) ... \mathbb{P}(X_n = i_n | X_{n-1} = i_{n-1})
$$

These two forms are used for the matrix entries:
$$
P_n(a_0, a_1) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n+1} = a_1 | X_n = a_0)
$$
$$
\pi_n(a_0) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = a_0)
$$
The probability of an example path is $(i_0, i_1)$:
$$
= \pi_0(i_0)P_0(i_0,i_1)
$$

Matrix form:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
\pi_0(i_0) & \pi_0(i_1)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
P_0(i_0, i_0) & P_0(i_0, i_1) \\
P_0(i_1, i_0) & P_0(i_1, i_1)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
A B = \begin{bmatrix}
\pi_0(i_0) P_0(i_0, i_0) + \pi_0(i_1) P_0(i_1, i_0) &
\pi_0(i_0) P_0(i_0, i_1) + \pi_0(i_1) P_0(i_1, i_1)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Have I performed the matrix multiplication step correctly?  I'm confused with the results of $(AB)_{0}, (AB)_{1}$ and why they do not correspond to a path as expressed above.  Instead the dot product is adding entries together.  I think I may be overlooking something crucial here.

Answer (score 1):

"Does anyone how form (b) becomes (c)?"

This is exactly what is called the markov property.

It is defined to be: If a sequence of Random Variables $\{X_n\}$  is such that $\mathbb P[X_n| X_{n-1},X_{n-2},\dots,X_1] = \mathbb P[X_n| X_{n-1}]$, then the sequence is said to have the Markov Property and the sequence is then called a [discrete time markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Discrete-time_Markov_chain)

In words, "The future is independent of the past given the present."

---

In your case you are given an initial probability distribution over the states $\pi$ and a transition matrix $P$. Each row $i$ of P indicates the transition probability from a particular state $i$. Each column represents the probability with which the chain will transition to $j$.

You have considered $\pi$ to be row vector, but it can also be considered as a column vector, in which case the multiplication
$\pi = \begin{bmatrix}
\pi(i_0)\\ \pi(i_1)\\
\end{bmatrix} P = \begin{bmatrix}
P_0(i_0, i_0) & P_0(i_0, i_1) \\
P_0(i_1, i_0) & P_0(i_1, i_1)
\end{bmatrix}$ would be $\pi(s')^\top = \pi(s)^\top P$ - is this the source of your question "Instead the dot product is adding entries together"?

In any case your multiplication is correct.

Comment: In regards to expressing as a column vector, it's my understanding matrix multiplication is defined on $A$ being a $m \times n$ and $B$ $n \times p$.  As you expressed, $\pi$ is a $2 \times 1$ and $P$ is $2 x 2$ and $1 \ne 2$ therefore these two matrices have incorrect dimensions for multiplication.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You are indeed correct that the dimensions have to match. But this is not different from $\pi(s')^\top = \pi(s)^\top P$ as the transpose is taken. Dimensionally, $(1\times 2)\cdot (2\times 2) \mapsto (1\times 2)$ in this case

Comment: So are you suggesting that $\pi$ be a column vector?  If so, then my original equation in the post represents that which I had questions on.